# Google Autocompleter and character encoding

Tags: php, html, special-characters, jquery-autocomplete

I am using this autocompleter from Google

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-autocomplete/ (if you click on "**Source**" you can find all the source files for the script)

and everything is working fine, except it's having problems with special Croatian characters (like č, ć, ž etc. I'm not sure if you'll see these, so here's an idea of what I am talking about: [link](http://fc03.deviantart.net/fs70/i/2011/037/a/7/croatian_alphabet_by_sternradio7-d38xvxc.jpg) - the letter c with a hachek on top etc.)

Here's the setup:

- an html file points to a jquery autocomplete script and a php file with the results array
- the metadata for the html file has a charset of utf-8, no other pages have any kind of encoding at all
- the array in the php file has those special characters encoded with html codes (the letter "ž" is replaced with `&#382;` so a typical array element looks like this: `"Po&#382;ega" => "5"`)
- when I enter a search string into the input field, the returning results are encoded correctly - Požega etc. **but** when I click the result to accept it, it enters `Po&#382;ega` into the input field, which is obviously not what I want
- when my search string has a special letter in it, the script doesn't find anything

How do I fix this? Should I just replace the HTML special codes in the array with the actual special letters(it seems to work fine then, but I'm not sure whether everybody will see this as I intended)? If not, how do I set the character encoding on all pages so the special letters display correctly on the input field and they're searchable?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Character encoding is such a pain in the ass with browsers. There are several things you can do to cover your bases, one of which you've already done.

1. Set the  tag to indicate charset of UTF-8
2. Use .htaccess to define a charset of UTF-8
3. Use PHP to define a charset of UTF-8 in the header (something like: header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');"

Making sure these are true should ensure that the data shows up on all UTF-8 supported browsers. By the way, I can see the special characters, so you must be doing something right. :)

Comment: I did the 2nd and 3rd points (put a .htaccess file with an AddDefaultCharset utf-8; added the header line in index.html (renamed it to php) and the other php file). Still doesn't work! So, I can see the special characters in the select box but when I click on an option to select it, it throws an html code (like `&#382;`). Grrr.